# How to replace all multiples in an array by a particular string in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an integer array like this

int[] arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

Now I want to change every multiple of 3 (but not multiple of 5) to 'AB', every multiple of 5 ((but not multiple of 3) to 'CD' & every every multiple of both 3 & 5 to 'ABCD

I want a dynamic solution which can be used for any number of elements of array - that the solution should stand irrespective of size.

I was trying like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 != 0)) {
            arr[i] = 'AB';
        }
        else if ((i % 3 != 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) {
            arr[i] = 'CD';
        }
        else if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) {
            arr[i] = 'ABCD';
        }
    }
```

But it is giving error in Eclipse as i am unable to assign string value in integer array. I am beginner in Java, that is why I am requesting someone to help me in this regard.

The final array will be
[1, 2, AB, 4, CD, AB, 7, 8, AB, CD, 11, AB, 13, 14, ABCD, 16, 17, AB, 19, CD];

Comment: An `int[]` can hold `int` values. A `char` is an integral type. The issue is `'AB'` is **two** characters, and thus is not a valid character. Have you considered `'C'`?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I want to change every multiple of 3 (but not multiple of 5) to 'AB', every multiple of 5 ((but not multiple of 3) to 'CD' & every every multiple of both 3 & 5 to 'ABCD

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a modified version of [Fizz buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz). There's a couple mistakes that I can spot off the bat.

```
if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 != 0)) {
```

In the above snippet, you're checking if `i` (the iterator of the for-loop) is a multiple of `3` and `5`. However, you want to check if the **array element at position `i`** is a multiple of `3` or `5`. To do that, you can change the above snippet to the following:

```
if ((arr[i] % 3 == 0) || (arr[i] % 5 != 0)) {
```

---

Next, your conditions seem to be incorrect. You want to check if the element at position `i` is a multiple of `3` **AND** the element at position `i` is not a multiple of `5`. To do that, you should use `&&` instead of `||`, like so:

```
if ((arr[i] % 3 == 0) && (arr[i] % 5 != 0)) {
```

---

Lastly, you're trying to store more than one character into a single `char` value, which isn't possible in Java. If you're required to use more than one character, then you should use a `String` instead. However, you won't be able to store a `String` in an `int[]`, so you'll need to create a `String[]`:

```
String[] newArray = new String[arr.length];

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if ((arr[i] % 3 == 0) && (arr[i] % 5 != 0)) {
        newArray[i] = "AB";
    } else if ((arr[i] % 3 != 0) && (arr[i] % 5 == 0)) {
        newArray[i] = "CD";
    } else if ((arr[i] % 3 == 0) && (arr[i] % 5 == 0)) {
        newArray[i] = "ABCD";
    } else {
        newArray[i] = Integer.toString(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

We also needed to add a case for when all conditions are `false`, as we want to retain the initial values in `arr` that don't satisfy any condition.

---

Taking `n` to be `arr.length - 1`, we can print the contents of `newArray` with:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Which produces the expected output:

```
[1, 2, AB, 4, CD, AB, 7, 8, AB, CD, 11, AB, 13, 14, ABCD, 16, 17, AB, 19, CD]
```

Comment: Hi I have changed the question a bit. Can you check now?

Comment: @tommy123 I've edited my answer to accommodate the modifications made to your question.

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray)); when printing this line 
I am getting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
 at SixthProblem.replace(SixthProblem.java:40)
 at SixthProblem.sumofMultiple(SixthProblem.java:34)
 at SixthProblem.main(SixthProblem.java:57)

Comment: That exception is not due to printing the array. I recommend you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: I cannot understand what the OP is trying to mean?

Comment: Ok got it i took arr.length intially. I had to take arr.length - 1

Comment: @tommy123 Did this fix your issue?